# изменения :before при использовании :hover

Tags: css, css3

Прописал для блока `.box:before`, нужно чтобы при использовании `.box:hover{}` изменялся его `:before`, возможно такое провернуть?

Comment: Ну, `box:hover:before{}` ?

Comment: лол,я писал  ```box:before:hover``` сао тебе добрый человек